# Don`t get icons on my TabWidgets

Tags: android, icons, android-tabhost

I am trying out a TabLayout example.

I have copied-pasted pretty much everything and it works. I just dont get the icons on the tabs. They are on the drawable folder with the state-list xml as well.

I have tried referencing the default app icon (which I know works well) and still won't show up on the tabs.

I have tried changing the titles for the Tabs to "Uno, Dos, Tres" as you can see on the code and the Tab titles DO change, but they always show in capital letters.

```
package com.example.androidtablayout;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Uno", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_livestreaming));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
        songspec.setIndicator("Dos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_livestreaming));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Tres", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_livestreaming));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

it seems I have accidentally solved it.

I just added this:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".AndroidTabLayoutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

to my Manifest.xml trying to make the default application title disappear from the top of the layout. This seems to have changed the whole sytle of the layout showing the icons and the titles in lower case.

Still don't understand exactly how this works. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <TabWidget
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    />
     <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
     >
     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >
     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:text="This is tab1"
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    />    

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >
     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:text="This is tab 2"
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    />

     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >
     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:text="This is tab 3"
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    />

     </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();

TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flash));

TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sun));
spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chart));
spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);
tabHost.addTab(spec3);
}
}
```